# Script or terminal command for enable or disable keyboard backlight

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, chromebook

i'm running elementary os 0.4 loki on a Chromebook Pixel 2013, and so far so good, i mean everything work just fine, relly you've done a good work! now i have just one thing that i'm not able to find, how to control the keyboard backlight, it stays always on, i wish to know if there is a command for disable and enable it, thanks in advance!

Comment: I have that same problem did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Toshiba Chromebook 2 with Loki 0.4, I've installed Tweaks and used this to fix my top row key commands "http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/blog/automate-chromebook-fixes-for-linux/" The brightness keys work however they don't affect anything other than the overlay that increases or decreases the brightness, and the keyboard backlight is broken on top of this.